# Adjusting vertical space taken by multiple row elements across different columns in HTML

Tags: html

I have to display some text in a table format. Some of my rows have more contents which can be further sub divided. 
My server side code generates the the table in the following strucutre.

I have taken an example of a row, which has 3 categories. Now each of the categories have a value which is displayed in the next column. 
Is there a way for me to ensure that Key1 and Value1 take up the same vertical space?

This is the HTML code generated by my backend:

```html
 <table width="30%">
      <tr>
        <th>key</th>
        <th>Value</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
            Key1-1<hr/>
            Key1-2<hr/>
            Key1-3<hr/>
        </td>
        <td>
            Value 1-1 Some Random Text blah blah
            More random Text <hr/>
            Value 1-2 Some Random Text blah blah
            More random Text<hr/>
            Value 1-3 Some Random Text blah blah
            More random Text<hr/>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

What I mean by same vertical space is the table generated by this code:

```html
  <table width="30%">
      <tr>
        <th>key</th>
        <th>Value</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
            Key1-1<hr/>
            Key1-2<hr/>
            Key1-3<hr/>
        </td>
        <td>
            Value 1-1 <hr/>
            Value 1-2 <hr/>
            Value 1-3 <hr/>
        </td>
        
        
      </tr>
    </table>
```

As can be seen when the text of either key or value is too long, the vertical space taken by the elements have a mistmatch.

Comment: This is clearly caused because there is "too much text" in the table.  What would you like to happen? Should the text be cropped? Should a scrollbox appear?

Comment: _"Is there a way for me to ensure that Key1 and Value1 take up the same vertical space?"_ - they _would_, if you made the whole thing a _proper_ table, instead of stuffing three separate _rows_ of data into single cells and using `hr` as a "separator" ...

Comment: @CBroe I have other columns as well. And each row which has these 3 keys are also divided on a different key.

Comment: _"And each row which has these 3 keys are also divided on a different key"_ - meaning what exactly? Please be specific, and show an actual example of the data you want to represent in table form. Maybe it will make sense to insert another table on a certain level, or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Use `whitespace: nowrap`.  It ensures the text on each row doesn't wrap to become multiple lines.  Also as @CBroe pointed out, you should be using proper table syntax:

```css
table{
  width: 500px !important;
  table-layout: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
}

tr{
  height: 20px;
}

td {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<table >
  <tr>
    <th>key</th>
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Key1-1
    </td>
    <td>
      Value 1-1 Some Random Text blah blah More random Text
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Key1-2
    </td>
    <td>
      Value 1-2 Some Random Text blah blah More random Text
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Key1-3
    </td>
    <td>
      Value 1-3 Some Random Text blah blah More random Text
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: This will keep expanding to the right of screen. Can't have unlimited scroll on the right. Some of it has to come vertical

Comment: @user1692342 how about something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a CSS hack since you said it's "HTML code generated by my backend".

```
td {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
}

td:nth-child(2) {
  left: 100px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y76y6on1/8/

If needed, you could use [CSS pseudo selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) to position rows.

Comment: Oh wait, this doesn't fully work.  You really should just use better table structure.  That's what tables are good for, rows and columns, tabular data.